# OSX Catalina / OSX Tiger - mouting any ISO problem

Tags: macos, osx-lion

I have problem with mounting ISO files under Mac OS Catalina (from the first version). I've try downloading ubuntu, deepin or any other ISO that was worked before upgrade to Catalina. My second old MacBook has OSX Tiger - same problem.

I've check MD5 of ubuntu iso - it is correct. Diskmounter say that this format is unmountable. Trying also thru disk tool - without luck. Using hdiutil - same result. And the best one - trying to boot iso thru VirtualBOX - works everything. Can anyone send me a some advice - what may be wrong ? Maybe Catalina has some bugs - but why it is not working on OSXTiger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- first attach the iso `hdiutil attach -nomount my.iso`
- second `diskutil list` to id the new dev

```
/dev/disk6 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        +1.3 GB     disk6
   1:                       0xEF                         8.9 MB     disk6s2
```

- then create a mount point `mkdir myiso`
- and finally mount your iso `mount_cd9660 -er /dev/disk6 myiso`

Comment: In mac os Big Sir I had to use:

`sudo mount_cd9660 -er /dev/disk6 myiso`

to get it to mount